# Help with bibliography in Latex

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{frame}

\cite{garrido2015cordic}
\cite{volder1960cordic}
\cite {wu2003high}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtraN}
\bibliography{citation}

\end{frame}
```

This is my code for bibliography but I have random numbers at the top. What is my mistake?

[image]

Comment: use \nocite{...} instead of \cite if you don't want  them to show up in the text.

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you my friend.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.